# Exporting Columns From MySQL to Excel Spreadsheet - PHP (Date Format Error)

Tags: mysql, excel, export

I am trying to export 3 columns|: `ReferenceNumber`, `CustomerName` and `DateOfSigning` from the table `Billing` from a MySQL database. At the moment the code below extracts the appropriate columns into an Excel file as I want but I have one small problem:

1. My DateOfSigning field in the Excel file is coming up as `#######`, the date format in the database is YYYY-MM-DD. Any ideas on how I would fix this?

My code:

```
 <?php

    //Export MySQL data to Excel File
            //Edit MySQL Connection Info:
            $DB_Server = "localhost";        //MySQL Server
            $DB_Username = "root";           //MySQL User Name
            $DB_Password = "";               //MySQL Password
            $DB_DBName = "dba";              //MySQL Database Name
            $DB_TBLName = "Billing";     //MySQL Table Name

        //DEFINE SQL QUERY:
        $sql = "Select ReferenceNumber, CustomerName, DateOfSigning FROM $DB_TBLName";

        //Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp for when file was generated:
        //Set $Use_Title = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
        $Use_Title = 1;

       //Define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
       $now_date = DATE('Y-M-D');

      //Define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
      $title = "Mandate Information - DB Alliance Ltd";
      /*

      */
      //Create MySQL connection
      $Connect = @MYSQL_CONNECT($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
      or DIE("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR() . "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
      //Select database
      $Db = @MYSQL_SELECT_DB($DB_DBName, $Connect)
      or DIE("Couldn't select database:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
      //Execute query
      $result = @MYSQL_QUERY($sql,$Connect)
      or DIE("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());

      //if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
      //if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
      IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1))
      {
       $file_type = "msword";
       $file_ending = "doc";
      }ELSE {
       $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
       $file_ending = "xls";
      }

      //Header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
      HEADER("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
      HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MDT_DB_$now_date.$file_ending");
      HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
      HEADER("Expires: 0");

      /*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */

      IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
      {
         /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
         //create title with timestamp:
         IF ($Use_Title == 1)
         {
             ECHO("$title\n\n");
         }

         //Define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
         $sep = "\n"; //new line character

         WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
         {
             //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
             $schema_insert = "";
             FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
             {
             //define field names
             $field_name = MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$j);
             //will show name of fields
             $schema_insert .= "$field_name:\t";
                 IF(!ISSET($row[$j])) {
                     $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                     }
                 ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "") {
                     $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                     }
                 ELSE {
                     $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                     }
            }
             $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
             $schema_insert .= "\t";
             PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
             //end of each mysql row
             //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row
             PRINT "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
         }
    }ELSE{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

     //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
     FOR ($i = 0; $i < MYSQL_NUM_FIELDS($result); $i++)
     {
         ECHO MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$i) . "\t";
     }
     PRINT("\n");
     //end of printing column names

     //start while loop to get data
     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j]))
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "")
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
             ELSE
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         //following fix suggested by Josue (thanks, Josue!)
         //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain \n or \r
         //these two characters are now replaced with a space
         $schema_insert = PREG_REPLACE("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         PRINT "\n";
     }
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Turned out to be an easy solution, the code is perfect, but in the Excel file, I simply had to highlight the date column and up at the top there is a drop-down box which I had to change to 'Short Date'. Although it already displays 'Date', it has to be re-selected.